# How to write a query for the following output?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables Names and Name_ids as shown below.

Platform : SQL Server 2005/2008.

```
Names table:
    Nam                              ID
    -------------------------------- -----------
    A                                1
    B                                2
    C                                3
    D                                4
    E                                5
    F                                6
    G                                7
    H                                8
```

and

```
name_ids table

ID
-----------
3
6
8
```

I would like to produce following output joining these tables.

```
Nam                              Nam_ID      ID
-------------------------------- ----------- -----------
A                                1           NULL
B                                2           NULL
C                                3           3
D                                4           3
E                                5           3
F                                6           6
G                                7           6
H                                8           8
```

The logic is match the nam_id to id and if nam_id is less than any id then return NULL.
If nam_id is greater than or equal to id, then return id. Here is the catch. In the above example, for F,6 we should not return F,6,3 combination but we should return only matching F,6,6.  when a matching item is found like 6,6, it should skip other matches like 6,3. And after that use 7,6 and not 7,3.
How do I write an sql query for the above?  The query is time intensive and need to execute fast.

```
Scripts:
Create table Names(Nam nvarchar(32), ID int);

insert into names values('A', 1);
insert into names values('B', 2);
insert into names values('C', 3);
insert into names values('D', 4);
insert into names values('E', 5);
insert into names values('F', 6);
insert into names values('G', 7);
insert into names values('H', 8);


Create table name_ids( ID int);
insert into name_ids values(3);
insert into name_ids values(6);
insert into name_ids values(8);
```

Please help.

Update:
I really appreciate your effort in providing solutions.  Now I am confused to pick the best performing query.  I have picked up few and trying to analyze the performance with very large result sets.

Comment: you did a good job of explaining, but we would like to see what you have tried so far

Comment: @vikiii, 4 is greater than 3 but less than 6.

Answer (score 5):

```
select n.Nam, 
CASE WHEN ni.ID IS NULL THEN (SELECT MAX(ID) from name_ids n1 where
                              n1.ID < n.ID)
                        ELSE  ni.ID
                        END
from Names n
left join name_ids ni on n.ID = ni.ID
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e582a/5)

Answer (score 2):

Please check my attempt:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT Nam, 
    a.ID Nam_ID, 
    MAX(b.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Nam) ID
FROM 
    Names a LEFT JOIN name_ids b 
        ON a.ID>=b.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.Nam, a.ID Nam_ID, 
      isnull(b.ID,(select max(id) from name_ids where id<a.id))
from Names a left outer join name_ids b
on (a.ID = b.ID);
```

[See DEMO here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e582a/14)

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but I may guess that downvotes comes from your previous version, which was wrong.

Comment: First step should appreciate, Second suggest/comment, last down-votes ~ down-voter should take time before down-vote: @RaphaëlAlthaus

Answer (score 1):

```
select Nam,id,
(select TOP 1 id 
      from name_ids 
      where name_ids.id<= Names.id 
      order by name_ids.id desc)
from Names order by id
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7856c/2)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
with cte as
(select i.*, row_number() over (order by id) rn
 from name_ids i)
select na.Nam, na.id Nam_id, s.id
from Names na
left join (select c.id, n.id next_id
           from cte c
           left join cte n on c.rn+1 = n.rn) s
       on na.id >= s.id and na.id < coalesce(s.next_id, na.id+1)
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7856c/5).

Answer (score 1):

```
select names.Nam, names.ID, max(name_ids.ID)
from names left join name_ids
on names.ID >= name_ids.id
group by names.Nam, names.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

it is simple to do :

```
SELECT A.Nam , A.Nam_ID , B.ID
FROM NAMES AS A 
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID
  FROM NAME_IDS AS B WHERE A.ID >= B.ID  
) AS B
```

I think this is more simpler version of inline query .

Comment: yes I checked it already but there is some problem with fiddle , I checked it in sql server management studio 2008 . Check http://prntscr.com/1dobbm

Comment: mhh maybe it's because of `OUTER APPLY`

Comment: i mean SQLFiddle had maybe a problem with it

Comment: yes I know that that means my ans is correct and proper but no one appreciate it . don't know why .

Comment: The issue is `SELECT *` that resulted in two ID columns in the output. Of course, you *could* blame it on SQL Fiddle, which for some reason shows only one ID column in this case and not the other. However, using `SELECT *` is rarely a good idea at all. Besides, the OP clearly specified the names of the columns in the output, so I'd say, by using `SELECT *` you were being a tiny little bit lazy. :)

Comment: I think my ans is most simpler then all other ans . select * is about sql fundamental . I think we are here to find best solution of the problem .